# What I need to declare in this scope?

Tags: c++

I'm doing this little program  in C++ but in codeblocks appears the following error: error:

> 'atod' was not declared in this scope

What I'm missing in this code? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class birth{
};


int main (void){

    int pass=1;
    string date, boy, aux1, aux2, aux4;
    double f;

    while(pass=! 0){
        cout<<"Enter the name of the birthday boy"<<endl;
        cin>>boy;
        cout<<"Enter the date of birth" <<endl;
        cin>>date;
        aux1= aux1.substr(5,10);
        f= atod(aux1);
        f=2012-f;
        cout<< "The birthday boy "<<boy<<"who born"<<date<<"now have"<<f<<"years"<<endl


        cout<<"Do you want to enter more birthdays?"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.- YES"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.- NO"<<endl;
        cin>>pass;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

EDIT: The problem is in this line:

```
 f= atod(aux1);
```

Comment: Use `strtod`, `stod`, a stringstream, or `boost::lexical_cast` for that.

Comment: By the way, your loop condition `pass=! 0` will loop forever.  It is constantly setting `pass` to non-zero (true).  You may have meant `pass != 0`.  Once you have that right, you need to look at the choices you give the user at the end of the loop and ask yourself if you're testing the correct value.

Comment: Often an error that says "...was not declared in this scope" means that you need a `#include` statement. You need to find out what header defines the `atod()` function if any. Or find the correct function name to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `atof` function.  It's in `stdlib.h`.  You need to pass a `const char*` to it, not a `std::string`.

```
f = atof(aux1.c_str());
```

Comment: Okay I do that, but when the program request me the date of birth, the program crash.. Do you know what can be?

Comment: Yeah, most likely it's the part where you try to pull a substring out of the empty string `aux1`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no any function like atod
use `_atold()` or `atof()` , these are in `math.h` & `stdlib.h`